# What does it mean when a function is called in the head of constructor() function?

Tags: solidity

I'm reading through some smart contracts and I noticed functions being called in the head of the constructor function, like MarginAdmin() in the following example.

```
constructor(address vault, address proxy)
    public
    MarginAdmin()
{
    state = MarginState.State({
        VAULT: vault,
        PROXY: proxy
    });
}
```

In this case, MarginAdmin is another solidity contract that is being imported into this file. What does this mean when a function gets called like this in the head of constructor function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the contract in question inherits from `MarginAdmin` (e.g. `contract Foo is MarginAdmin`).

`MarginAdmin()` is how the constructor for `MarginAdmin` (the "base class") is invoked.

See https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#inheritance for more details about contract inheritance.

Comment: That's correct. The only thing which bothers me in this case is why to call constructor without parameters ? It would be called anyway...Isn't it ?I think you can skip it and don't call MarginAdmin() at all.

Comment: Yes, I believe there's no need to explicitly invoke a parameterless constructor in the base class.

Comment: That seems like an unrelated question. Please create a new question to ask it.